# Difference b/w only Exclude and Omit (Pick & Exclude) Typescript

Tags: typescript

As per the definition of the [Pick @ typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), it constructs a new type for the mentioned properties only. [Exclude @ typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) is the opposite of it.

I've seen the following usage

```ts
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

But I don't quite get it. We could have simply used `Exclude` to leave out the non-required fields and constructed a new type of it. Why the combined `Pick` and `Exclude` is used as `Omit`?

Another example:

```ts
function removeName<Props extends ExtractName>(
  props: Props
): Pick<Props, Exclude<keyof Props, keyof ExtractName>> {
  const { name, ...rest } = props;
  // do something with name...
  return rest;
}
```

Can't the return type of above be re-written with `Exclude` as `Exclude<Props, ExtractName>`?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You are right about **`Pick`**, it takes an object type and extracts the specified properties. So:

```
 Pick<{ a: string, b:string }, 'a' > === { a: string }
```

The opposite of this is actually the later added **`Omit`**. This type takes an object type and removes the specified properties from the type.

```
 Omit<{ a: string, b:string }, 'a' > === { b: string }
```

**`Exclude`** is a different beast, it takes a union type and removes a constituent of that union.

```
Exclude<string | number, string > === number
```

`Exclude` is  defined as:

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

This means that `Exclude` will return `never` if `T` extends `U`, and `T` if it does not. So this means that:

- `Exclude<string, number>` is `string`
- `Exclude<string, string>` is `never`

The thing is that conditional types [distribute over naked type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). So this means that if applied to a union we get the following:

```
Exclude<string | number, number>
    => Exclude<string, number> | Exclude<number, number> // Exclude distributes over string | number
    => string | never => // each application of Exclude resolved to either T or never
    => string  // never in unions melts away
```

`Exclude` is used in the definition of `Omit`. `Exclude<keyof T, K>` takes a union of the keys of `T` and removes the keys specified by `K`. And then `Pick` extracts the remaining properties from `T`.

**Edit**

While both `Omit` and `Exclude` take two type arguments (and no relationship is enforced between the two) they can not be use interchangeably. Look at the result of some applications of these types:

```
type T0 = Omit<{ a: string, b: string }, "a"> //  { b: string; }, a is removed 
type T1 = Exclude<{ a: string, b: string }, "a"> // { a: string, b: string }, a does not extend { a: string, b: string } so Exclude does nothing 

type T2 = Omit<string | number, string> // Attempts to remove all string keys (basically all keys) from string | number , we get {}
type T3 = Exclude<string | number, string> // string extends string so is removed from the union so we get number
```

Comment: Actually I experimented with it and replaced my Omit with Exclude. Typescript throws no errors in that case. 

`export type NativeButtonProps = {
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>,
    htmlType?: ButtonHTMLType
} & IBaseButtonProps & Exclude<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<any>, 'type' | 'onClick'>;`

Comment: @kushalvm in both types there is no imposed relationship between the two type parameters, so they will accept any types. The difference is what they do. I think that your use of `Exclude` there was a mistake, and you actually need `Omit ` since you probably wanted to remove the keys `type` and `onClick`

Comment: Correct. I want to remove these two keys.  So if they're specifically designed for special types. One for union and other for objects. Shouldn't typescript throw error in this situation or why should it even accept the object if it only works for union type. I can do the same task with both. Hope, we agree here!

Comment: @kushalvm `Exclude` is just a conditional type, which exploits the distributive property of conditional types. At its root all it does is test if one type extends another. If it does it returns `never` otherwise it returns the type. This could be useful outside of unions but is most commonly used with unions. There is also no good way to enforce that a type parameter is a union so ts can't at present error on that even if it wanted to. Also in practice `Exclude` is often used to test seemingly unrelated types si enforcing a relation between type parameters would make it less useful.

Comment: @kushalvm as to Omit there is a long discussion as to why is isn't more strict but since it was added later the team surveyed what was actually in use and chose a version that works well and is the most compatible with existing versions.

Comment: @kushalvm also, just to make sure, in your previous comment you say you can do the same task with both. This is incorrect, they both compile, but the types they produce are not the same

Comment: Uff...too High level to understand for now. Any examples or links to help me understand better this difference?

Comment: @kushalvm I provide examples of what both do in my answer. Not sure what is not clear. I will try to add some counter examples when I get back to a pc.

Comment: @kushalvm Added more explanations, hope it is more clear, let me know if I can help with anything

Comment: Ok. What if we do this `type T1 = Exclude<{ a: string, b: string }, { a: string}>

=> Exclude<{ a: string}, { a: string }> | Exclude<{ b: string}, {a: string}>
=> never | { b : string }

=> {b : string }`. By your explanation, I broke it down and the answer was `{b: string}` as desired.

Comment: @kushalvm distribution happens over unions.. you are breaking up an object type. This is not behavior that exist in typescript. `Exclude<{ a: string, b: string }, { a: string}>` will just be `never` since `{ a: string, b: string }` does extend `{ a: string}`. You can see the resulting types if you hover in the playground over the type name: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgDFAvFAogDwMYBsCuATCAHgG8oBDALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGigCMrbHWoAvh1KUa9ZiwEA+IA

Comment: Yes. Excellent stuff! "playground hover" -that's what I was missing I guess to inspect.

Comment: Probably one of the best explanation I have read on conditional types!