# Omit helper is not working with Mapped Object Type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use `Omit` utility type to create a mapped type and it's giving me an error. Please consider the example below:

I have a type with literals like this

```
type something = 'abc' | 'bcd' | 'cde' | 'def';
```

I want to create a Mapped type like this

```
type mappedType = {
    [k in something]: string;
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
type mappedType = {
  abc: string;
  bcd: string;
  cde: string;
  def: string;
}
```

This works fine but let's consider if I want to omit one property.

```
type mappedTypeWithOmit = {
    [k in Omit<something, "def">]: string;
}
```

The above code doesn't work. Whereas if I use `Exclude` instead of `Omit`, I am able to get the desired result:

```
type mappedTypeWithExclude = {
    [k in Exclude<something, "def">]: string;
}
```

This is strange because Omit should give the same result as it also uses Exclude under the hood

```
/**
 * Construct a type with the properties of T except for those in type K.
 */
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

[Click to see code in typescript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/tests/baselines/reference/mappedTypeUnionConstraintInferences.js#L2)

The error I am getting is

```
Type 'Omit<something, "def">' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'Omit<something, "def">' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

You can also check this in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMoF4oDkAhgEYDGBUAPoeQCaU0Fl0SOGsBmBA3AFB8A9IKio0MKAHc4AJwDWMPqEhQiMmURABhFBDJy8UAN58oZqAG0DmWImTpsAXQBcsYDMxZ+AXyEiAklJEGMCicFCIaKFwGNBgMnCQMqBSuhhQZDIQRMCeESQAVnqhyhACwqLoEnRwEDAYBMBK4NAIRGCQdAAqLQDqUSgA8ghRhibmltbpw1EAPPBIYtgANFAARFxrAHwubh7YPuUiYhLAcOHS8hLBdFBYaABudbBESFAkEChED2hwAK4yVQSGZNUpQNodCDdPoDACiAA8yAAbP6sMamcxWKA2BHI1EQeZ2JZYVYbCCcba7GDuTyHMxAA)

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `Omit` and `Exclude` are not synonymous. Wouldn't you be looking for: `type mappedTypeWithOmit = Omit<arrayCheck,'def'>` ?

Comment: `Omit` omits a property from the interface/type, `Exlude` exludes a type from a union.

Comment: Thank you, Spender and Roberto.  I think I got the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Omit is used on interface or object type and we are trying to use it on union string literal. That's why the error.

Usage:

```
type mappedType = {
  abc: string;
  bcd: string;
  cde: string;
  def: string;
}

type mappedTypeWithOmit = Omit<mappedType,'def'>
```

This will be equivalent to

```
type mappedTypeWithOmit = {
  abc: string;
  bcd: string;
  cde: string;
}
```

Exclude is different, it is used to exclude a union type.

Usage:

```
type something = 'abc' | 'bcd' | 'cde' | 'def';
type somethingWithExclude = Exlude<something, "def">
```

This will be equivalent to

```
type somethingWithExclude = 'abc' | 'bcd' | 'cde';
```

Now we can go ahead and use this to create a mapped type.

```
type mappedTypeWithExclude ={
  [k in somethingWithExclude]: string;
}
```

And it will be equivalent to

```
type mappedTypeWithExclude = {
  abc: string;
  bcd: string;
  cde: string;
}
```

Read [Difference b/w Exclude and Omit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916532/difference-b-w-only-exclude-and-omit-pick-exclude-typescript) for more info.