# TypeScript provide alternative types while using keyof

Tags: typescript

I want to have a type that when specifying a specific key as the value to the property `answerMethod` (e.g. `answerMethod: 'options'`) it should require an additional field (e.g. a string array with options)

Here is a non-working attempt at what I've been wanting to achieve:

```js
const formComponents = {
  text: TextInput,
  options: Radio,
}

interface AnswerBase {
  name: string
  label: string
  helpText?: string
  value?: string
}

interface AnswerWithoutOptions extends AnswerBase {
  answerMethod: Omit<keyof typeof formComponents, 'options'>
}

interface AnswerWithOptions extends AnswerBase {
  answerMethod: 'options'
  options: string[]
}

type Answer = AnswerWithoutOptions | AnswerWithOptions

const answer: Answer = {
  name: 'title',
  label: 'Title',
  helpText: 'The title of the video.',
  answerMethod: 'notavalidmethod', // Expected an error.
  value: '',
}
```

The above code only allows the field `options: string[]` when `answerMethod: 'options'`, but it doesn't restrict `answerMethod` to be a key of `formComponents` and allows any string. `answerMethod` should only allow keys of `formComponents`.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916532/difference-b-w-only-exclude-and-omit-pick-exclude-typescript

Comment: It sure does. I guess I'll be setting aside some time to read up on utility types.

Comment: It's a mistake I make all the time, and I suspect we're not the only ones. :-) If that other question's answers answer this one, I should probably delete my answer below. You'll have to un-accept it before I can do that. Happy coding!

Comment: It's not clear to me why I didn't delete my answer when I found the duplicate. If you like, you can un-accept my answer and I'll delete it. Happy coding!